# How to sort a List<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>> by T1 and T3 ascending

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, tuples

I want to sort the following triple tuple list by T1 and T3 ascending:

```
var datalist= new List<Tuple<long, string, string>>();
```

- first: Sort by first tuple (long) ascending
- if there are entries with the same number (long) then sort alphabetically ascending by the last tuple (the last string)

**Possible sorted output:**

- 123123, xxx, zz
- 444555, ybc, aa
- 444555, abc, bb

With this code a can sort the list by the first tuple (long), but not by the last tuple (last string):

```
datalist.Sort((x, y) => x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1));
```

Comment: How about `var sortedList = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item3).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x => y` is short for `x => { return y; }`.

Instead of a single `return` statement, the body can then be modified to contain anything you like.

```
datalist.Sort(
    (x, y) => {
      var result = x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
      if (result == 0)
        result = x.Item3.CompareTo(y.Item3);
      return result;
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to do the second comparison in cases where the first results in equivalence:

```
datalist.Sort((x, y) => {
    var cmp = x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
    return cmp == 0 ? x.Item3.CompareTo(y.Item3) : cmp;
});
```

Alternatively you could use `OrderBy` followed by`ThenBy` and the `ToList` to put them in a list again; it's rather wasteful when you already have a list and won't be using the original order for something else, but it is a tad more expressive:

```
datalist = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item3).ToList();
```

Of course the cost of that expense rises both with the size of `datalist` and how often this operation will be done.

On the other hand, if you're only going to enumerate through this once, then omiting the `ToList()` reduces this cost since no new list is created, and if your enumeration might exit ahead of the full cycle (e.g. after finding some items that meet a given criteria) then it could even be more efficient than the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` combination:

```
var result = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item3);
```

Comment: Fixed to store result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq to solve it. First add the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then using [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.95).aspx), for sample:

```
var result = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item3);
```

If you need to sort in a `descending` order, you also can see [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`TheByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534489(v=vs.100).aspx).

You can call OrderBy and many TheBy you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` functions of `System.Linq`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var datalist= new List<Tuple<long, string, string>>();
        datalist.Add(new Tuple<long, string, string>(123123, "xxx", "zz"));
        datalist.Add(new Tuple<long, string, string>(444555, "ybc", "bb"));
        datalist.Add(new Tuple<long, string, string>(444555, "abc", "aa"));
        datalist = datalist.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item3).ToList();
        foreach(var data in datalist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", data.Item1,data.Item2, data.Item3);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LNYCjA